# Hide value of a field being logged with Logging Aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I want to hide the value of a field in my logs if it contains a certain value. For example, if "sectionType" = "image", then I don't want to show this value as it makes the logs hard to read.

I have made an attempt at the logic:

```
public void beforeAdvice(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    final String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();
    final String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    final List<Object> args = Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs());
    args.stream().forEach(a ->
    {
        if (a.getClass().equals(CreateBlogRequest.class)) {
            ((CreateBlogRequest) a).getSections().stream().forEach(s -> {
              if(s.getSectionType().equals("image")) {
                 // Now what?
              }
            });
        }
    });
    log.info("Invoking: " + className + "." + methodName + "with args:" + args);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this may be?

```
 public void beforeAdvice(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
final String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();
final String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
final List<Object> args = new ArrayList<>();

 Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs()).forEach(a -> {
  if (a.getClass().equals(CreateBlogRequest.class)) {
    ((CreateBlogRequest) a).getSections().stream().forEach(s -> {
      if(s.getSectionType().equals("image")) {
        return;
      }
      args.add(a);
    });
  }
  args.add(a);
});
log.info("Invoking: " + className + "." + methodName + "with args:" + args);
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).